# (netbeans) (JApplet) >> JApplet simply doesn't show

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, japplet

i wrote this code (MVC).... there are:

- package MAIN,    files (Main.java)
- package CONTROL, files (Control.java)
- package VISTAS,   files (Proceso.java)  "views"

in CONTROL.Control:

```
package CONTROL;
import VISTAS.Proceso;

public class Control {
    private Proceso proceso1;
    public Control()
    {
       proceso1 = new Proceso();
    }

    public void iniciar()
    {
       proceso1.init();
    }
}
```

in VISTAS.proceso:

```
package VISTAS;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Proceso extends JApplet implements Runnable{
    public Thread esteProceso;
    public int segundos;

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        esteProceso = new Thread(this);
        segundos = 0;
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        esteProceso.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
     while(true)
     {
        segundos++;
        repaint();
        try{esteProceso.sleep(1000);}catch(InterruptedException ex){}
     }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
      System.out.println("are you running?");
      g.drawString("Segundos: "+String.valueOf(segundos),20,20);
    }
}
```

Problem: I'm trying to run this in NetBeans... it runs but nothing is visible.

Comment: Applets are dead in technology - best to move on

Comment: Applets are also suppose to be loaded within web pages - although the Java Plugin ins no longer supported and most browsers actively disable it - making the technology a waste of time investing in.

Comment: thanks i didn't know that